# Programmatically change the state of a switch

Tags: android

I have a switch which enables/disables something on hardware by sending requests over cloud.
What I need is to change the state of the switch programmatically and only programmatically. However, the state won't be changed, unless the switch gets response from the hardware telling that the request has been applied.
I tried that by sending the request using onCheckedChangeListener, but when the user swipes the handle it goes forward and backward. Then forward again, when it receives the response, this handler shouldn't be moved, unless it receives the response, even if the user tries to drag it.

Here is my code:

```
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(!doNotChange) {
                mPresenter.sendEnableRequest(isChecked);
                mySwitch.setChecked(!isChecked);
            }
            doNotChange = false;
        }
    });
```

Then when I get the response I change the state of the switch if the request was successful.

```
void onResponseReceieved() {
    doNotChange = true;
    mySwitch.setChecked(isChecked);
}
```

Comment: Please show the code of `sendEnableRequest`. Did you get any error message? Have you stepped through the program by debugger to see where did it stop?

Comment: The function just to send the data to the server there is no problem with it. My problem when the user swipes the handle of the switch rather than clicking it, it triggers OnCheckedChange but not OnClick so I want to prevent the user from swiping the handle.

Comment: Then you can just `setOnCheckedChangeListener` to do whatever you want when user swipe it.

Comment: You're right, but if the request wasn't successful for some reason the state of the switch mustn't be changed. To be more clear, I might send a request and get no answer because this request might be lost in the network. So the switch mustn't change unless it gets the response with success.

Comment: Can't you just do `mySwitch.setChecked(!isChecked);` in `OnCheckedChangeListener` just like what you did in `OnClickListener`? What's the difference?

Comment: Yes, it will work. But I have to put a flag when I change the state of Switch, I mean when I call mySwitch.setChecked(icChecked) because it will trigger the OnChangeStartListener() so this flag helps me to not send data or do any thing because I trigger it not the user. However, this way will make the handle go forward and backward then forward again when the response comes, I'd like to avoid this movement.